# Add one element to multiple lists at once python

Tags: python, list

I have an 2D-array of lists, I wanted to know if it was possible to append one element to all lists at once without going through all elements with a double loop.

Let's say I have this array of lists :

```
matrix_of_lists = np.array([[2,3],[1]],
                           [[2,5,4],[2,5]]])
```

I want to do something like :

```
matrix_of_lists[:].append(6)
matrix_of_lists = np.array([[2,3,6],[1,6]],
                           [[2,5,4,6],[2,5,6]]])
```

I know how to do it with two loops but I want to optimize/accelerate the process. My array of lists is already in a loop and is very big: 1000*1000.

It might not be possible.Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can't have that array. ->`SyntaxError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [0]: matrix_of_lists = np.array([[[2,3],[1]],[[2,5,4],[2,5]]])

In [1]: foo = lambda l:l.append(6)

In [2]: vfunc = np.vectorize(foo)

In [3]: l = vfunc(matrix_of_lists)

In [4]: matrix_of_lists
Out[4]: 
array([[list([2, 3, 6, 6]), list([1, 6])],
       [list([2, 5, 4, 6]), list([2, 5, 6])]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: What is `vfunc`?

Comment: vfunc = np.vectorize(foo)

Comment: Fair enough. IMO it is better to keep an element to append as an argument to the vectorized function. Otherwise, you will need to make a new vectorized function for each value you want to append.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you can gain much performance from vectorization because your array ultimately stores list references. But here is one approach that avoids writing loops and works for arbitrary shapes.

```
@np.vectorize
def append_vec(mat, elt):
    mat.append(elt)


append_vec(matrix_of_lists, 1) # works inplace
# array([[list([2, 3, 1, 1]), list([1, 1])],
# [list([2, 5, 4, 1]), list([2, 5, 1])]], dtype=object)
```

A better way without creating an array of `NaN`s.

```
def append_vec(mat, elt):
    mat.append(elt)
    return None


append_vec = np.frompyfunc(append_vec, 2, 0)
```